# Question on Specular reflection behaviour?

Tags: graphics, visualization, computer-vision

Why Specular reflected light will be in bright color(usually white) while other parts of the object are reflecting the perceived  color wavelength?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a physical perspective, this is because:

- specular reflection results from light bouncing off the *surface* of material
- diffuse reflection results from light bouncing around *inside* the material

Say you have a piece of red plastic with a smooth surface.  The plastic is red because it contains a red dye or pigment.  Incoming light that enters the plastic tends to be reflected if red, or absorbed if it is not; this red light bounces around inside the plastic and makes it back out in a more or less random direction (which is why this component is called "diffuse").

On the other hand, some of the incoming light never makes it into the plastic to begin with:  it bounces off the surface, instead.  Because the surface of the plastic is smooth, its direction is *not* randomized:  it reflects off in a direction based on the mirror reflection angle (which is why it is called "specular").  Since it never hits any of the colorant in the plastic, its color is not changed by selective absorption like the diffuse component; this is why specular reflection is usually white.

---

I should add that the above is a highly simplified version of reality:  there are plenty of cases that are not covered by these two possibilities.  However, they are common enough and generally applicable enough for computer graphics work: the diffuse+specular model can give a good visible approximation to many surfaces, especially when combined with other cheap approximation like bump mapping, etc.

---

Edit:  a reference in response to Ayappa's comment -- the mechanism that generally gives rise to specular highlights is called [Fresnel reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel%27s_equations).  It is a classical phenomenon, depending solely on the refractive index of the material.

If the surface of the material is optically smooth (e.g., a high-quality glass window), the Fresnel reflection will produce a true mirror-like image.  If the material is only partly smooth (like semigloss paint) you will get a specular highlight, which may be narrow or wide based on how smooth it is at the microscopic level.  If the material is completely rough (either at a microscopic level or at some larger scale which is smaller than your image resolution), then the Fresnel reflection becomes effectively diffuse, and cannot be readily distinguished from other forms of diffuse reflection.

Comment: :So you mean - "If we assume a surface is made up of small particles, all particles will diffuse as well as exhibit specular refelction also(in some particular direction).If we see from a particular angle ,and , if we are in the specular reflected angle we see the exact reflected light(which was not absorbed at all by the surface)" ?? Am I right?

Comment: In graphics, the specular component does not have to be an exact mirror reflection; typically, you get a "specular highlight" that is a few degrees wider than your light source.  Physically speaking, you need a surface which is at least somewhat smooth (on a microscopic scale) to get a specular component; if your surface is totally rough at that level, you will get diffuse reflection instead.

Comment: Basically, the reason why the specular/diffuse thing works is that there are many actual surfaces whose appearance it approximates fairly well.  That does not mean all surfaces with that appearance work the same way, physically.  Also, there are plenty of surfaces whose appearances *don't* fit that model; if you want to render them, they need special treatment.

Comment: @comingstrom suppose incoming light that enters the into any red object then except red everything get absorbed. Then this red light which I see is refraction or reflection light? I seem it's refraction? What is right?

Comment: As described above, the red/diffuse component will refract into the plastic, then eventually out again.  In between, physically speaking, it may reflect from pigments inside the plastic, or suffer a combination of reflection and refraction from microscopic polymer crystallites, or something else.  There are many physical processes that can produce a diffuse reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Its a question of [wavelength absorption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_%28electromagnetic_radiation%29) vs reflection.

First, specular reflections do not exist in the real world. Everything you see is mostly reflected light (the rest being emissive or other), including diffuse lighting. Realistically, there is no real difference between diffuse and specular lighting : its all a reflection. Also keep in mind that real world lighting is not clamped to the 0-1 range as pixels are.

Diffusion of light reflected off of a surface is caused by the microscopic roughness of the surface (microfacets). Imagine a surface is made up of millions of microscopic mirrors. If they are all aligned, you get a perfect polished mirror. If they are all randomly oriented, light is scattered in every direction and the resulting reflection is "blurred". Many formulas in computer graphics try to model this microscopic surface roughness, like [Oren–Nayar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oren%E2%80%93Nayar_reflectance_model), but usually the simple Lambert model is used because it is computationally cheap.

Colors are a result of wavelength absorption vs reflection. When light energy hits a material, some of that energy is absorbed by that material. Not all wavelengths of the energy are absorbed at the same rate however. If white light bounces off of a surface which absorbs red wavelengths, you will see a green-blue color. The more a surface absorbs light, the darker the color will appear as less and less light energy is returned. Most of the absorbed light energy is converted to thermal energy, and is why black materials will heat up in the sun faster than white materials.

Specular in computer graphics is meant to simulate a strong direct light source reflecting off of a surface like it may do in the real world. Realistically though, you would have to reflect the entire scene in high range lighting and color depth, and specular would be the result of light sources being much brighter than the rest of the reflected scene and returning a much higher amount of light energy after one or more reflections than the rest of the light from the scene. That would be quite computationally painful though! Not feasible for realtime graphics just yet. Lighting with HDR environment maps were an attempt to properly simulate this.

---

Additional references and explanations :

[Specular Reflections :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection)

Specular reflections only differ from diffuse reflections by the roughness of a reflective surface. There is no inherent difference between them, **both terms refer to reflected light**. Also note that diffusion in this context simply means the scattering of light, and diffuse reflection should not be confused with other forms of light diffusion such as subsurface diffusion (commonly called subsurface scattering or SSS). Specular and diffuse reflections could be replaced with terms like "sharp" reflections and "blurry" reflections of light.

Electromagnetic Energy Absorption by Atoms :

Atoms seek a balanced energy state, so if you add energy to an atom, it will seek to discharge it. When energy like light is passed to an atom, some of the energy is absorbed which excites the atom, causing a gain in thermal energy (heat), the rest is reflected or transmitted (passes "through"). Atoms will absorb energy at different wavelengths at different rates, and the reflected light with modified intensity per wavelength is what gives color. How much energy an atom can absorb depends on it's current energy state and atomic structure.

So, in a very very simple model, ignoring angle of incidence and other factors, say i shine RGB(1,1,1) on a surface which absorbs RGB(0.5,0,0.75), assuming no transmittance is occurring, your reflected light value is RGB(0.5,1.0,0.25).

Now say you shine a light at RGB(2,2,2) on the same surface. The surface's properties have not changed. Reflected light is RGB( 1.5 , 2.0 , 1.25 ). If the sensor receiving this reflected light clamps at 1.0, then **perceived** light is RGB(1,1,1), or white, even though the material is colored.

Some references :

[page at www.physicsclassroom.com](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/u12l2c.cfm)

[page on ask a scientist](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/phy00/phy00232.htm)

[Wikipedia : Atoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom#Energy_levels)

[Wikipedia : Energy Levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_level#Energy_level_transitions)

Comment: Hai, I haven't came across saturation limit of particles which will lead to specualr reflection.Can you pls give me some pointers for that theory?

Comment: btw, you mentioned about HDR light and in Computer graphics we clip it to 0-1. So do you mean there is intense(brighter) light which has more intensity than white(255,255,255) used in computer graphics ??? pls clarify this pls...

Comment: Concerning HDRI (High Dynamic Range Imaging): in real life there is absolute black (no light), but no absolute white. You could have 1e+100 x the luminosity of the sun. This does not translate to display hardware which functions within a fixed range of luminosity and color which clamps at 1.0. One method to try and solve this is to store a luminosity range higher than 1 in an image (hence "high range") and then dynamically "expose" for the range you want in the final image, much like you would set exposure settings on a camera (hence dynamic).

Comment: so as u said there will be, so other colors which have more intensity than  red(255,0,0) will be there right? Some consoles/devices will have more than 32 bit color depth suport, can they display those values? btw thanks for ur comments...

Comment: The problem is not the color model. The Unreal Engine currently supports floating point high range color. The problem is the display hardware. Even if you have 64bits per channel of color, you still have to convert that to an 24bit image for the display device. Your TV does not go above "white". In order to simulate high range in a fixed range image, you have to implement exposure, much like a camera will capture a fixed range of luminosity within the high range world lighting.

Comment: This is the first I've seen of this saturation resulting in full spectrum reflection. Specular reflection can happen in dark rooms with a very small light source, and are still mostly in the mirror direction unlike diffuse reflection.

Comment: On absorption saturation, maybe i am incorrect in my understanding of photon-atom interactions. The original question was not why specular reflections happen but rather why they tend to return the full spectrum when the material returns a specific color. I still think this has to do with light intensity vs material absorption, but i cannot find a reference either for _or_ against this. Maybe it is that there are no perfect absorbers and at high intensity the returned spectrum saturates the viewing sensor to white... Anyways, I will edit my answer to omit the statement.

Comment: On specular reflections, that you can see them along the reflection vector in a small room is a property of the reflective surface, not light. I have to maintain that specular light is an abstract concept that does not exist in the physical world but rather simply describes a set of conditions. It is a good affordable visual approximation for computer graphics, but it does not exist.

Comment: @zen: one last question.Actually for this question only i went for previous question.If we have 64 bit color buffer and we are limited to 24bit frame display buffer finally,how can the Dynamic range can be achieved(as anyways it will be going to be clipped right??)?

Comment: Yes, it will always be clipped at final output. Dynamic range is simulated by dynamically selecting a fixed range of exposure within a wider range of data. See ["Tone Mapping"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping) and ["HDR Rendering"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDR_rendering).

Comment: ok,Actually i read about tone mapping...but still can't get how the hrd rendering will give a different output as, the final bit depth is fixed :(